# MediaBrowserCompat queue find item

Tags: android, android-mediasession

As per [Uamp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) sample when `onPlayFromMediaId` is called its `mediaId` is matched with list of `queueitems` already stored using `iterator` as below

```
public static int getMusicIndexOnQueue(Iterable<MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem> queue,
         String mediaId) {
    int index = 0;
    for (MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem item : queue) {
        if (mediaId.equals(item.getDescription().getMediaId())) {
            return index;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

this works great unless you have some thousand items in your list, its lags badly, is there any way I can get the index on queue in this scenario?

P.S.- This code is from v1 branch although v2 kotlin based branch has the same concept.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API available that gets you this directly. So, you have to build your own data structure.

I created a HashMap of MediaId's as key and Index as its value. This will help you fetch the QueueItem faster. The question then becomes, when to create this HashMap. I created this in the callback when you are fetching the media List (QueueItem) from the device. The idea is to create this Map in background.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> mediaIndexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int index = 0;
for (MediaSessionCompat.QueueItem item : queue) {
    mediaIndexMap.put(item.getDescription().getMediaId(), index++);
}
```

Hopefully this preprocessing QueuItem should work for constant time lookup/fetch.

Comment: That will lead to store the same data twice, I will prefer passing Index of the selected item to retrieve from already stored list, though that requires more work but much efficient than this

Comment: You can always build a map which stores a combination of mediaId and Index as key and gets you the QueueItem. Don't deal with the list of QueueItem at all. Its just my suggestion. Don't think google has offered anything else.